# Profile seems to be broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

This is how the profile page looks as of now:

[image: Tiny Giant's profile.. I was not stalking, I swear]

The question is: Is this a bug or a feature? It doesn't look like a feature :/

Comment: What you call a bug, the devs call a feature ;)

Comment: It is just an unknown random feature that was released just today. Congrats!

Comment: The devs are investigating.

Comment: We can spin the wheel of blame to find out whos fault it is: http://jsfiddle.net/AYPpF/82/embedded/result/ :P

Comment: I have to second @Nathan. It looks like an improvement for me.

Comment: This is caused by `width: 100%;` rule for `.row` selector in the `story.css` stylesheet.

Comment: @Seth Doesn't look fixed to me- But I notice the issue does not exist at all on Meta.

Comment: Maybe it is a small test to see if they can fit ads left and right of your profile picture?

Comment: @Kendra That's what I was getting at, I didn't notice the profiles on SO where still having this issue :)

Comment: @rene Opening a new room, "SO meta conspiracy crafting"!

Comment: We're trying a thing where users who surpass a (proprietary) level of "General Awesomeness" have their avatar section expanded to a width more befitting of their greatness. You, sir, have a lot to be proud of.  Or it's a bug.

Comment: I knew it! I am great!

Comment: @SterlingArcher When all are great... noone is :)

Comment: @Seth https://cdn.meme.am/instances/400x/63113523.jpg

Comment: @SterlingArcher [Well played...](http://s2.quickmeme.com/img/ea/eab1f096e033aa247f2af062ad9b9aad982639915ef2e966795aefa1a654b7b7.jpg)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Fix incoming in next build (build rev `2016.9.14.4986` on MSE/MSO, `2016.9.14.3984` on sites)

Comment: What did you dev's copy and past this time?

Comment: @PetterFriberg as an Italian, I proudly copypasta. I never copy and past.

Comment: @PetterFriberg something from SO ;)